# Returning object- OnPostExecute

Tags: java, android

I try to return array of objects with this function:

```
  public static JSONEvent[] invokeFunction(String funName, String requestContent) {

        final String functionName = funName;
        final String requestPayload = requestContent;

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, InvokeResult>() {
            @Override
            protected InvokeResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    final ByteBuffer payload =
                            ENCODER.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(requestPayload));

                    final InvokeRequest invokeRequest =
                            new InvokeRequest()
                                    .withFunctionName(functionName)
                                    .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse)
                                    .withPayload(payload);

                    final InvokeResult invokeResult =
                            AWSMobileClient
                                    .defaultMobileClient()
                                    .getCloudFunctionClient()
                                    .invoke(invokeRequest);

                    return invokeResult;
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    Log.e("LAMBDA", "AWS Lambda invocation failed : " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    final InvokeResult result = new InvokeResult();
                    result.setStatusCode(500);
                    result.setFunctionError(e.getMessage());
                    return result;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final InvokeResult invokeResult) {

                try {
                    final int statusCode = invokeResult.getStatusCode();
                    final String functionError = invokeResult.getFunctionError();
                    final String logResult = invokeResult.getLogResult();

                    if (statusCode != 200) {
                        //showError(invokeResult.getFunctionError());
                    } else {
                        final ByteBuffer resultPayloadBuffer = invokeResult.getPayload();

                        //resultPayloadBuffer.rewind();
//                        while (resultPayloadBuffer.hasRemaining())
//                            Log.e("BUFFER",resultPayloadBuffer.position() + " -> " + resultPayloadBuffer.get());

//                        User a = new User(23, 24);
//
//                        User b = new User(58, 59);
//                        User[] ab = new User[] {a, b};

                       // User [] events = new User[3];

                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();





                        final String resultPayload = DECODER.decode(resultPayloadBuffer).toString();
                        Log.e("LAMBDA-SUCCESS", resultPayload);
                        try {
                           // String s2 = getJson2(ab);
                           // Log.e("S2", s2);
                            //User[] user2 = mapper.readValue(resultPayload, User[].class);
                            events = mapper.readValue(resultPayload, JSONEvent[].class);

//                            for (JSONEvent u : events)
//                                Log.e("USER",u.getLocationLat()+"");

                            Log.e("ARRAY",Arrays.toString(events));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //return resultPayload;
                        // mResultField.setText(resultPayload);
                    }

                    if (functionError != null) {
                        Log.e("LAMBDA", "AWS Lambda Function Error: " + functionError);
                    }

                    if (logResult != null) {
                        Log.d("LAMBDA", "AWS Lambda Log Result: " + logResult);
                    }
                }
                catch (final Exception e) {
                    Log.e("LAMBDA", "Unable to decode results. " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    //showError(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }.execute();

        return events;
    }
```

The problem is that I call invokeFunction in diffrent activity and it returns null but in onPostExecute the array is not null. It seems that it returns array before calling OnPostExecute. How to solve that?

Comment: You probably getting value before your AsyncTask finished it's work and provided result. Call the task and use result from onPostExecute. For example inside onPostExecute you can call another method say updateUi(events). Just do the job you need inside this method

Comment: To be honest I tried to implement your advice but I doesn't work. Can you help me with some code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method invokeFunction is finishing before onPostExecute (asynchronous)
You could use an interface to communicate AsyncTask and activity.

Interface (pseudocode):

```
public interface AsyncCom {
    public void sendUsers(User [] events);
}
```

Your asynFunction (pseucode):

```
public void invokeFunction(String funName, String requestContent, AsyncCom listener) {
    ...
```

And call the function of the listener in postExecute (pseudocode):

```
protected void onPostExecute(final InvokeResult invokeResult) {
    ...

    listener.sendUsers(events);

    }
```

Declare the interface in your activity and call your method with the listener (pseudocode):

```
public class MyActivity implements AsyncCom {

    ...

    invokeFunction(funName, requestContent, this);

    ...
```

Finally, in your activity, implements the returned method (pseudocode):

```
public void sendUsers(User [] events){
    // do wathever you want with users
}
```

But remeber that the response will bw asynchonous

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void invokeFunction(String funName, String requestContent{
    YourTask task = new YourTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{funName, requestContent});
}

static class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InvokeResult> { 

    @Override
    protected InvokeResult doInBackground(String... params) {

        String funName = params[0];
        String requestContent = params[1];

       // ... 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final InvokeResult invokeResult) {

       ///  . .. 
        doWhatYouNeedWithTheResult(result);
    }
    };
}
```